# Requirement to dynamically assign keyboard shortcuts by the end user

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a requirement where the keybindings can be modified by the end user in a form.

How do i accomplish this change ? As of now the keyboard shortcuts are static and i have handled them in the keydown event using a basic if condition like ,

```
if(key=='Z' & key=='Ctrl')
 //then undo
```

this way .

How do i accomplish this in C#

Comment: What have you tried? Is there something you're stuck on, or are you just asking us for code?

Comment: I m looking at design approach for this requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a lookup structure. The key is the possible command or the key combination - depending what you want to do. in the key handling routing, you can query the lookup (generated from config and/or manually changed bindings while the current instance runs) with the keycode combination and the result would be the command/action.